# Send data using AJAX after delay time

Tags: php, ajax

I have an array Group ID.

And i want to using Ajax to submit it after delay time and show result "success" or "error" notice.

Each submit time it will auto visit one website.

Example

> First time: visit abc.com/?id=$id //$id from above array.

After delay time it will visit the second page

> visit abc.com/?id=$id //the 2nd id from above array.

How i can do it? Plz give me detail. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "each submit time it will auto visit one website"?

Comment: When i submit.
The first time it will auto visit a.com/?id=1
After delay time...
The 2nd time it will auto visit a.com/?id=2
1 and 2 will get from Group ID array

Comment: @VũCôngTịnh What means auto visit? You mean sent ajax to that urls?

Comment: I mean view that site without open new window

Comment: @TaronSaribekyan Any idea, please!

Comment: @VũCôngTịnh How does the AJAX come into play? Where does the AJAX get submitted?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I have a group list, i will get it into an array( contains ID of group) and one Delay time input field, and one submit button. When i submit it will auto view 1st page.
The first page abc.com?id=1
After delay time it will view 2nd page: abc.com?id=2
With: 1 and 2 we get from ID array, delay time get from input field.

Comment: @VũCôngTịnh From that description, it sounds like you are not using AJAX and you are not looking to submit anything. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know how to do it using Ajax or another way. I am newbie can you expain me? @MaximillianLaumeister

Comment: @VũCôngTịnh Is this similar to what you had in mind? https://jsfiddle.net/yxjdag6u/2/